# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (99) - With docker-compose

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am trying to connect to MySQL DB of **local machine** with docker-compose,
I write the following code on the docker-compose file:

```
  db-my-sql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql_db
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: "xyz"
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root1234!"
    ports:
      - "3307:3306"
    network_mode: "host"
```

And then I got the following error:

**mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (99)**

**I would appreciate your help and solution
How do I connect to MySQL from my local machine.**

**Thanks !**

Answer (score 0):

Its because you have ports conflicts.
if you are using 3306 in your computer (a MYSQL process maybe) you can kill the process that is using that port, or just use another port for your docker.

Comment: But when I change the port it does go up
But I can't connect to MySQL local machine

Comment: I got the following error:


mysql.connector.errors.DatabaseError: 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (99)

Comment: 1. your database is running in localhost at port 3306? 2. Port Mappings FROM_WHERE:TO_WHERE FROM_WHERE is the port of your PC, and TO_WHERE the port of your container. I recommend for local development to put high numbers like 8500+. Make sure that the firewall on your local machine is not blocking connections to the MySQL server. If nothing works you can check the logs (? https://www.sumologic.com/blog/mysql-log-file-location/

Comment: I checked, everything looks good, but it's not work

Comment: You can use: "host.docker.internal", but I found it easier to run a separate MySQL Container and connect to that IP address.